# Tinymce and n1ed and codeigniter - cannot integrate the filemanager

Tags: php, codeigniter, tinymce

I am trying to integrate the filemanager from n1ed into codeigniter3.  According to the docuementation, I need a vendor library which I load with "use EdSDK\FlmngrServer\FlmngrServer;" but after that I need to set some default paths of which I don't understand how.  This is my controller;

```
 <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

 use EdSDK\FlmngrServer\FlmngrServer;

 class MH_Admin_Filemanager extends MY_Admin_Core {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
 

FlmngrServer::flmngrRequest(
    array(
        'dirFiles'  =>  '../upload/filemanager_dir/files',
        'dirTmp'    =>  '../upload/filemanager_dir/tmp',
        'dirCache'  =>  '../upload/filemanager_dir/cache'
    )
);

}
```

Obviously the above produces an error.  I am not familiar with :: and also how would I set the array paths in codeigniter?  Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: You can't just put random code directly inside `class foo {  random code... }` outside of the class methods. All code must be _inside_ methods. I would recommend that you go through the basics of classes and objects in the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Yes, I get that.  How would I set those vars though?

Comment: _"Yes, I get that"_ - Looking at the posted code, I disagree. Please read the link I posted properly (from start to finish). It explains how classes work, what `::` is and works and more. If's a pretty extensive walkthrough. The only syntax issue in the posted code is the location of the `FlmngrServer::flmngrRequest()`-call. Where it should be in the code depends on when you want it to be executed, which we don't know.